# SetState inside function of React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am determining the users OS platform and setting state based on it. I have a function which determines the users OS platform and i am trying to setState, But the property inside the state is always returning false.

Here is my Component.

```
class HowtoDownload extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
                windows: false,
                chromebook: false,
                ipad: false,
                mac: false,
}
        componentDidMount() {
            console.log("How to Download Component Mounted");
            this.getUserPlatform();
            console.log(this.state.windows);
        }
 getUserPlatform = () => {
            var OSName = "UnknownOS";
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") !== -1)
                OSName = "Windows";
                this.setState({windows: true});
        }
}
```

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous in React - you cannot log it immediately after setting it. You can use the [callback option](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-setstate-callback-in-react) of `this.setState` which will always execute its callback function after state is set.

Comment: as @lawrence-witt said you can't, but you can console inside the render() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. So after the state has been updated, it won't called again.

To see the updated result, you can use the `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method. You can fetch the result in `render()` method to.

Also React updates state asynchronously, if you want to see the updated state when it's done, you should use the callback function of `setState` which gets fired as soon as the state gets updated:

```
this.setState({windows: true}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.windows)
})
```

)